# SQL Table Join with Wildcard Variables

Tags: sql

I have two joined tables. Table 1 has client data and table 2 has their status.

I need to have a wildcard name search but I only want it to return results based on a status from table 2. This works when I actually enter some data in the @ClientName variable but when it is left empty it returns all records and ignores the @ClientStatus variable. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
DECLARE @ClientName NVARCHAR (100) = '' 
DECLARE @ClientStatus INT = 1 

SELECT DBO.CLIENTS.CLIENTID, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.FIRST_NAME, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.LAST_NAME, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.PHONE_NUMBER, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.MOBILE_NUMBER, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.HOUSE_ADDRESS_NUMBER, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.STREET_NAME, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.TOWN_CITY, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.POST_CODE, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.CLIENT_SOURCE, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.CLIENT_STATUS, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.DATE_ADDED, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.CALL_DATE, 
       DBO.CLIENTS.CALL_TIME, 
       DBO.CLIENT_STATUS.CLINIC_STATUS 
FROM   DBO.CLIENTS 
       INNER JOIN DBO.CLIENT_STATUS 
               ON DBO.CLIENTS.CLIENT_STATUS = DBO.CLIENT_STATUS.STATUSID 
WHERE  ( DBO.CLIENT_STATUS.CLINIC_STATUS = @ClientStatus ) 
       AND ( DBO.CLIENTS.LAST_NAME LIKE @ClientName + '%' ) 
        OR ( DBO.CLIENTS.MOBILE_NUMBER LIKE @ClientName + '%' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm going to guess that you actually want to group your `OR` condition since it has a higher precedence than `AND`

```
AND (( DBO.CLIENTS.LAST_NAME LIKE @ClientName + '%' ) 
    OR ( DBO.CLIENTS.MOBILE_NUMBER LIKE @ClientName + '%' ))
```

More importantly, it's not ignoring the variable. When you don't supply anything for `@ClientName` the final condition becomes

```
( DBO.CLIENTS.LAST_NAME LIKE '%' ) 
    OR ( DBO.CLIENTS.MOBILE_NUMBER LIKE '%' )
```

Since `%` is a wildcard, you're telling it to match on anything. In order to get around this, you'll either want to require a name to be passed in, or handle NULL/blank input in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Or has higher operator precedence than and, so change your query to the following:

```
WHERE  ( DBO.CLIENT_STATUS.CLINIC_STATUS = @ClientStatus ) 
       AND (( DBO.CLIENTS.LAST_NAME LIKE @ClientName + '%' ) 
        OR ( DBO.CLIENTS.MOBILE_NUMBER LIKE @ClientName + '%' ))
```